# PHP Regex for Time options HH:MM optional SS and optional am/pm/AM/PM

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regex pattern that will match the following times:

- 09:15:42
- 09:15:42 am (or AM or pm or PM)
- 09:15
- 09:15 am (or AM or pm or PM)

Here's what I have so far, but it's not making the seconds optional:

```
'~^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])\h*?([ap]m)$~i'
```

The code is:

```
$pattern = '~^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])\h*?([ap]m)$~i';
return preg_match($pattern, $time);
```

Thanks

Comment: You could also just use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. It does not support optional stuff, but with only four valid formats you could put them in an array and try to parse them in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need place to an optional quantifier `?` after the last two groups.

```
~^(0[0-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?\h*([ap]m)?$~i
```

However, if you wanted to grab the match results of each group instead of validating the string, the above would capture the colon inside of the third group. You can simplify as well as fix the behavior using the below expression.

```
~^(0\d|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)(?::((?2)))?\h*([ap]m)?$~i
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sQ1qY7/3)

Comment: what if its like 8am - 6pm or 8pm - 6pm in the sub string?

Comment: Then obviously the regex would need to be modified.